# Update records in database from an object list repeatedly

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a list with this objects:

```
public class Foo {
    public String title;
    public String subject;
}
```

For example: `List<Foo> mFoo = new ArrayList<Foo>();`

And I have a table in my database with same name and same attributes.

This list has about 1000 objects. When this list is processed the first time, all objects will store in the database.

The next times, some objects of the List will change or some new objects will add it too. Here is the problem.

How can I update and to add the new objects to database to avoid load all stored objects in the database on other list and then to compare both lists?

Does it exist some way which will minimize to access to database? (I don't want load 1000 objects each time)

### **Edit 1: Expanding information**

I obtain the `List<Foo> mFoo` from a method that parses an external source data (html code). Then I have objects as Foo that I save in the database.

When I save an object I get an id;

```
public class Foo {
    private String id; 
    public String title;
    public String subject;
}
```

Each time I execute the method I get a List that could contain object Foo that already exist in the database, but I haven't its id, because they are new instances.

Comment: So, just to clarify, the database AND the list will change (desync)?

Comment: No. When the list will changes (an object changes or it adds new objects), the database must save the changes from the list.
But I cannot update the database each time an object is added or it changes. I have full lists and I have to compare with the records in the database. (As a merge operation)

Comment: Then the answer provided is ok. Although I might suggest having a second list, when something is changed/added you put it in the second list... then you only load the second list into the database. Would that work for your situation?

Comment: I've added some extra information. Unfortunately I can not use it

Comment: Then I suspect you are doomed to need to compare them all... maybe you can consider some reengineering to make it so that it's not like this? I mean, so that you can keep the IDs or so that when the method runs you don't lose everything you already have?

Comment: Maybe exist an alternative: What about use title attribute as primary key? I mean, the title must be unique and it is an index, and if I use it although data come from external source, I will have always the id (primary key) of the table. But I have read that using an String like primary key it isn't very recommended because performance is affected.

Comment: Yes, maybe if we could see a bit more code... Like what does the table look like? and maybe the function that changes the List and even the code you use to update the database? Pretty sure I (or someone) can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest some flag for marking instances as beeing dirty:

```
public class Foo {
  private String title;
  private String subject;
  private boolean isDirty=true;


  public void onPersist(){
    this.isDirty=false;
  }

  public String setTitle(String title){
    this.isDirty=true;
    this.title=title;
  }

  //more setters und getters

}
```

**Edit 1**

As d'alar'cop pointed out you seems to have no choice but to query the database against title and/or subject.

But according to your tags you are using sqlite. If you have control over the tabledefinition you could look into the [ON CONFLICT [REPLACE|IGNORE]](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)  clause with unique constraints in the create statement. That way you should be able to insert your list and let the do database its job.

Best regards,
sam